# Snowflake COPY INTO feature - Can we increase the file size limit(default 16MB) when loading file from STAGE > SNOWFLAKE

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Problem:
I have CSV and JSON files in Azure blob which I want to load to Snowflake, some files are more than 16MB in size.

I understand there is a **default limit of 16MB for COPY INTO**. Is there a way of increasing this?

Snowflake documentations say its possible when unloading data (snowflake > data file) but there is no mention of changing the limit when loading data (data file > snowflake).

Look forward to your answers & thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no file size limit of 16MB for COPY INTO. There are recommendations about using files with 100-250 MB (or larger) in size compressed as described [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-considerations-prepare#general-file-sizing-recommendations).

The 16MB limit refers usually to semi-structured data.
If the data is complex or an individual value requires more than about 16MB of storage space, then you can use more than one of the preceding techniques. For example, you can split the data into multiple columns, and some of those columns can contain an explicitly-specified hierarchy of data types. This is also documented [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/semistructured-intro).

For best practices on data ingestion I would recommend these blog posts:

https://www.snowflake.com/blog/best-practices-for-data-ingestion/

https://www.snowflake.com/blog/best-practices-for-data-ingestion-part-2/

https://www.snowflake.com/blog/data-ingestion-best-practices-part-three/